# Dataframes with pandas set index as date_range , but when it is set all the values becomes NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have done manipulation on reading the excel file as data frame. My code is this:

```
import pandas as pd
sheetname = "３月"
required_cols = list(range(3,34))

df1 = pd.read_excel('./weather_data/konpira_plan.xls',
                    sheet_name=sheetname,usecols=required_cols,inplace=True)
rows=[2,4,5,6,9,10,11,14,15,16,19,20,21]
df=df1.loc[rows].T
cols=['Date','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L']
df.columns = cols
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df
```

My output is this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc5NZ.png)

i want to change the index to date_range from 2019/03/01 but when I change it using this function:

```
date_index = pd.date_range('2019/03/01', periods=31,freq='D')
df2=df.reindex(date_index)
```

I am getting this output:
All the values becomes NaN.
i am very new working with pandas and dataframe.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHHc3.png)

This works for only 1 excel sheet if I use more than 1 excel sheet it gives me error:

```
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

at this point:

```
df_w=df1.loc[rows].T
```

Comment: if you read using `pd.read_excel` with out specifying the sheet name , the output will be  a dictionary containing a DataFrame for every sheet. you can iterate through the dictionary using `for sheet_name, df1  in your_dictionary_name.items():`

Comment: ok but what is your_dictionary_name.items()?

Comment: `your_dictionary_name` is the variable to which you are reading the excel to. Keep `sheet_name = None` to get you data frame `df1` in correct format, your code should be :`your_dictionary_name = pd.read_excel('./weather_data/konpira_plan.xls',
                    sheet_name=None,usecols=required_cols)      for sheet_name, df1 in your_dictionary_name.items():    rows=[2,4,5,6,9,10,11,14,15,16,19,20,21]
df=df1.loc[rows].T ..........(rest of your code)..................... df.to_excel('new_file.xls',sheet_name)`

Comment: it gives error when sheet_name=None

Comment: whats the error? are all sheets on your workbook `konpira_plan.xls` similar, so that you can select `required_cols = list(range(3,34))` from all the sheets?

Comment: it only upgrades 1 excel sheet not working with other excel sheet

Comment: @Shijith It depends on the month days if its 3 then its March the range would be (3,34) , if its 4 then April the range would be (3,33)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign index and create `date_range` by number of rows with `periods=len(df)` for general solution, if is possible number of rows should be changed:

```
date_index = pd.date_range('2019/03/01', periods=len(df),freq='D')
df.index = date_index
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked but how to save df as excel/csv file

Comment: @KrupaliMistry By `df.to_csv(filename)`

Comment: @KrupaliMistry - Or `df.to_excel(filename)` - [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: This works for only 1 excel sheet if I use more than 1 excel sheet it gives me error

Comment: df.to_excel(filename,sheet_name) for multiple excel sheets. go through the documentation first

Comment: @KrupaliMistry - `This works for only 1 excel sheet if I use more than 1 excel sheet it gives me error:` - what is your code for multiple excel sheets? Each sheet has same format and need apply solution from my answer?

Comment: @jezrael I have applied for your answer , the code remains same for all the sheets in excel